# Volume empty after container restart

Tags: docker

I am experiencing that the volume is empty when restarting a container.

Command for the first time start of the container is

```
docker run -d --name ${dockerId} --memory="512m" --restart=always -v volume-${dockerId}:/app/public:Z -p ${port}:80 --network my-network ${dockerId}:v1
```

Any idea what can be done?

Comment: Build the container before running it.

Comment: you mean running the above command again ?

Comment: rebuilding it didnt work. the volumes data gets deleted upon container stop i think

Comment: Is the `dockerId` variable consistent across deleting and and recreating the container?  Is your application actually using the `/app/public` directory?  How are you verifying the volume is empty?

Answer (score -1):

I found a great solution.

https://sysadmins.co.za/guide-to-setup-ranchers-convoy-volume-driver-for-docker-swarm-with-nfs/

Using convoy plugin for docker.